# Sql/Dapper: How do perform LIKE in WHERE clause for array of values?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, dapper

I have a table with a lot of employees in it, every person has a Name column with their full name.

I then want to do a query similar to this when searching for people:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @value1 + '%' AND Name LIKE '%' + @value2 +'%' AND so forth...
```

for an arbitrary array of values.

My Dapper code would look something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> Search(string[] words)
{
  using var connection = CreateConnection();
  connection.Query<Employee>("SELECT * etc.", words);
}
```

Is there ANY way to do this with SQL without resorting to string concatenation, and the risk of SQL Injection attacks that follows?

Caveat: I don't know how Dapper actually passes an array to the query, which limits my creative ideas for working around this :-D

And also: Changing the Table structure is, unfortunately, out of the question. And I'd rather avoid fetching every single person into .Net memory and doing the filtering there.

Comment: `DynamicParameters`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there ANY way to do this with SQL without resorting to string concatenation, and the risk of SQL Injection attacks that follows?

Because the set of where conditions is not fixed you will need to build the query dynamically. But that does not mean you cannot parameterise the query, you just build the parameter list alongside building the query. Each time a word from the list add to the condition and add a parameter.

As Dapper doesn't directly include anything that takes a collection of `DbParameter`, consider using ADO.NET to get an `IDataReader` and then Dappter's

```
IEnumerable<T> Parse<T>(this IDataReader reader)
```

for the mapping.

Such a builder would be very roughly

```
var n = 0;
for (criterion in cirteria) {
  var cond = $"{crition.column} like @p{n}";
  var p = new SqlPatameter($"@p{n}", $"%{crition.value}%";
  conditions.Add(cond);
  cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
}

var sql = "select whetever from table where " + String.Join(" and ", conditions);
cmd.CommandText = sql;
var reader  = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
var res = reader.Parse<TResult>();
```

Comment: `DynamicParameters` seems to be a object which takes a collection of parameters? Or am I missing something?

Comment: That would be even simpler (I've previously only needed to do this kind of thing in the days before ORMs...)

Comment: The combination of your answer and `DynamicParameters` seems like the perfect solution, thanks a bunch :-)

Answer (score 1):

**For performance reasons, it's much better to do this as a set-based operation.**

You can pass through a datatable as a Table-Value Parameter, then join on that with `LIKE` as the condition. In this case you want *all* values to match, so you need a little bit of relational division.

First create your table type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.StringList AS TABLE (str varchar(100) NOT NULL);
```

Your SQL is as follows:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Employees e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM @words w
    WHERE e.Name NOT LIKE '%' + w.str + '%' ESCAPE '/'   -- if you want to escape wildcards you need to add ESCAPE
);
```

Then you pass through the list as follows:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Employee> Search(string[] words)
{
  var table = new DataTable{ Columns = {
    {"str", typeof(string)},
  } };
  foreach (var word in words)
    table.Rows.Add(SqlLikeEscape(word));    // make a function that escapes wildcards

  using var connection = CreateConnection();
  return connection.Query<Employee>(yourQueryHere, new
    {
      words = table.AsTableValuedParameter("dbo.StringList"),
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if want to add where condition and above the where you can add Loop for run through all the element in array.

For Sql with dapper you can add

```
var builder = new SqlBuilder();

/**Add Loop Here**/
.Where($"LOWER(ColumnName) LIKE @Value", new { Value = "%"+Class.Object.ToLower()+"%" });


var selector = builder.AddTemplate("SELECT * FROM TableName /**where**/");

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   var results = await connection.QueryAsync(selector.RawSql, selector.Parameters);
   return results.ToList();
}
```